# How can I get Locale and Language from the device, with Kotlinmultiplatform

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I am creating my first app on kotlin multi-platform, and a need to get some device's information like language and maybe country.

I am looking for a way to get on both devices, android and iOS, using Kotlin multi-plataform.

It is possible? Or it's only possible make this on native way on both devices?

Answer (score 17):

Something like the following.

Common

```kotlin
expect val myLang:String?
expect val myCountry:String?
```

iOS

```kotlin
actual val myLang:String?
    get() = NSLocale.currentLocale.languageCode

actual val myCountry:String?
    get() = NSLocale.currentLocale.countryCode
```

Android

```kotlin
actual val myLang:String?
    get() = Locale.getDefault().language

actual val myCountry:String?
    get() = Locale.getDefault().country
```

Answer (score 0):

jetbrains.compose.ui-1.6.0

```
import androidx.compose.ui.text.intl.Locale

Locale.current.language
```